# string indices must be integers not str dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to get value form a list in a dict? not sure how it can be accessed? but here's what I did & I'm getting a error as 
**TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str**

```
lloyd = {
    "name": "Lloyd",
    "homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
    "quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
    "tests": [75.0, 90.0]
}
alice = {
    "name": "Alice",
    "homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
    "quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
    "tests": [89.0, 97.0]
}
tyler = {
    "name": "Tyler",
    "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
    "quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
    "tests": [100.0, 100.0]
}

for i in alice:
    print i['quizzes']
```

I'm learning python, & I had few more queries If anyone could help would be a gr8 help in learning.Thanks in advance.

1) How to access the key 'homework' & sum its value in list?

2) How to access dict alice & sum its values of all keys? homework + quizzes + tests with sum() function

3) How to access the key 'llyod' & get its len() of a list? say 'homework'

this is what I tried & I got the same error for this one as well:

```
def average(x):
    for a in x: 
       return sum(a['homework']) / len(a['homework'])
       return sum(a['quizzes']) / len(a['quizzes'])
       return sum(a['tests']) / len(a['tests'])
```

If anyone could please clear my doubts on those above 3 question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### question1(How to access the key 'homework' & sum its value in list?)

```
>>> sum(lloyd['homework'])
354.0
```

#### question2 homework + quizzes + tests

```
def findsum(x):
    return sum([sum(x['homework']),sum(x['quizzes']),sum(x['tests'])])

>>> findsum(lloyd)
741.0
```

#### question3) How to access the key 'llyod' & get its len() of a list? say 'homework'

```
>>> len(lloyd['homework'])
4
```

Answer (score 7):

You are looping over the *keys* of `alice`, not the values. Your keys are strings. Even if you were looping over the values, none of the values in `alice` can be indexed by `'quizzes'`. You could just print `alice['quizzes']`, but that is probably not what you wanted to start with.

You want to put all your named dictionary into one 'parent' dictionary instead:

```
students = {
    "lloyd": {
        "name": "Lloyd",
        "homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
        "quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
        "tests": [75.0, 90.0]
    },
    "alice": {
        "name": "Alice",
        "homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
        "quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
        "tests": [89.0, 97.0]
    },
    "tyler": {
        "name": "Tyler",
        "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
        "quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
        "tests": [100.0, 100.0]
    },
}
```

Now you can loop over *this* dictionary and access various keys per student:

```
for student_data in students.values():
    print student_data['quizzes']
```

Note the use of `.values()` here to loop over *just* the values of the `students` dictionary, as we don't use the keys here.

Use the same loop to calculate your averages, but remember that a function *ends* when a `return` statement is encountered. You can always return multiple values from a function by returning a tuple:

```
def average(student):
    homework = ...
    quizzes = ...
    tests = ....
    return (homework, quizzes, tests)
```

or you could use a dictionary, for example.

Comment: I suspect that is the next step of the exercise ;).

Comment: +1 you are right it is better to pull all in one 'parent' dictionary

Comment: +1 @martijn hmm.. a different approach but a cool way to get what I want. Thanks, 
yeah you are correct about the exercise part :) definitely helpful to get going through exercise.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
 for i in alice:
        print i['quizzes']
```

takes the dictionary Alice and goes iterating on its keys, which are strings. I think what you want is:

```
print alice['quizzes']
```

Answer (score 0):

better, that you use the iteration over both (key and value). It is more generally. Try it, it works:

```
values_of_alice=[]
for key, value in students.iteritems():
    if key == 'alice':
        values_of_alice.append(value)
for key2, value2 in values_of_alice[0].iteritems():
           if key2 == 'quizzes':
               print value2
```